# Getting error while installing react-stripe-js in my react Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, stripe-payments

Getting this error on trying to install `npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js`.
Can anyone help ?

```
C:\Users\Ayush\Desktop\ReactBootcamp\amazon-clone>npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js
npm ERR! Object for dependency "@babel/generator" is empty.
npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ayush\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-11T07_04_49_530Z-debug.log
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjBQO.png)

Answer (score 0):

try below steps

```
Delete node_modules folder
Delete package-lock.json file
run npm cache clean --force
npm install
```